# Is it a Markov chain?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $ X_1, X_2, \dotsc $ be a sequence of Markov dependent and Bernoulli distributed random variables. Set $ D_n = I( X_n > X_{n+1}) $, that is
\begin{align}
D_n = \begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{if } X_n > X_{n+1}, \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Is the sequence $ D_1, D_2, \dotsc $ also a Markov chain? Why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $X$ is a homogenous Markov chain on the state space $\{0,1\}$.
Then, each $X_n$ is $\{0,1\}$-valued, and $D_n=1$ when $X_n=1$ and $X_{n+1}=0$, thus, $D_n=1$ implies $D_{n+1}=0$.

Furthermore, if $D_n=1$, the first time $n+N$ after $n$ such that $D_{n+N}=1$ is distributed as $H_1+H_0$ where $H_1$ is the first hitting time of $1$ by the Markov chain $X$ starting from $X_0=0$, and $H_0$ is the first hitting time of $0$ by the Markov chain $X$ starting from $X_0=1$.

Thus, $H_1$ and $H_0$ are independent geometric random variables, and the only case where $H_1+H_0-1$ is geometrically distributed, as it should be for $D$ to be a Markov chain, as the first hitting time of $1$ by $D$ starting from $0$, is when $P(H_1=1)=1$ or $P(H_0=1)=1$.

To sum up, $D$ is not a Markov chain, except if one of the transitions $0\to0$ or $1\to1$ has zero probability for $X$.

Comment: **According to the first formula, $ P(X_n - X_{n+1} > 0) = 1/2 $ for all distributions of X. Do you think that is right?**

Comment: Yes (in bold or not in bold): if $(X,Y)$ is i.i.d. with a continuous distribution, then $P(X=Y)=0$ and $P(X<Y)=P(X>Y)=\frac12$. (Proven in almost every first course on probability theory.)

Comment: Doesn't $X$ has to be Bernoulli distributed? Like a random variable taking values ${0,1}$ or does it mean something else in this setting?

Comment: @Shashi Good catch, please see revised version.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this modified version.

Comment: Niiice! ${} {} {} $

Comment: @Shashi Thanks for the appreciation, and for having put me back on track...